# Possible Prior Art for PCT/US2013/057893

Tags: barcode, us8532632, wo2014036568a1

It seems that there exists prior art for [PCT/US2013/057893 by Game Concourse, Inc.](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2014036568A1?cl=en) (filed Sep 3, 2013)

Can someone refer to [US 13/068,782 by Wesley Boudville](https://www.google.com/patents/US8532632) (filed May 16, 2011) and confirm the same?

Regardless of the status of their US Provisional from 2012, my patent subsumes theirs.